# Bar graph of your searches frequency

Tags: graphs, search, history

Is there a tool that creates a bar graph of your searches representing number of searches on the vertical axes and time on the horizontal?

For example, if I searched for "how to bake potatoes" and "tom hanks plane movie" - so a total of 2 search terms at 1:00 PM, and a 1 search term at 2:00 PM, none at 3 PM, 4x at 4 PM, 2x at 5 PM, ... it produces the following graph:

```
Searches
^
4                ____
3                |  |
2 ____           |  | ____
1 |  | ____      |  | |  |
0 |  | |  | ____ |  | |  |
  1:00 2:00 3:00 4:00 5:00 > Time
```

Requirements:

- It should have the flexibility on the time axis, allowing by minutes, hours, days, weeks, ..
- It should use the search data from either my browser or google account
- OS: Windows. License: Any. Price: Any

Answer (score 0):

What tools are available likely depends on what search engine you are using.

I use Bing myself, which has a "search history" feature if I use my outlook login.  Navigate to Bing -> hamburger menu (top right) -> Search History.  This will give you an interactive UI to view your search history, and clear it if needed.  If you click on "Learn More" under "Privacy Matters", it will take you to [this page](https://account.microsoft.com/privacy/), where you can download your search history (looks like it gives me a zip of a csv which I can open in excel and manipulate to make graphs and charts).

It looks like google has a similar feature, but as of writing I don't see a good way of exporting or analyzing that data outside of Google's own ecosystem.

Duck duck go doesn't have any such tools (that I can find), for obvious reasons since the platform is designed around privacy.